# RPostgreSQL - import large table into R without losing data

Tags: r, postgresql, time, rpostgresql

I'm trying to import a very large data that includes timestamp formatted as "2015-08-31 07:23:25.3"
The table has almost 2.5mil rows and when I import it into the dataframe, it loses time.

```
table1 <- dbReadTable(db_connection, "table_name")
```

Above is the code I have used.
It works fine with another table with the same format timestamp and has 800 rows.

I have used following code to check if anything is hidden... no luck :-(

```
unclass(as.POSIXlt(table1$timestamp))
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Well consider this:

```
R> library(anytime)
R> anytime("2015-08-31 07:23:25.3")
[1] "2015-08-31 07:23:25.2 CDT"
R>
```

Standard rounding error not entirely uncommon on numeric data such as dates.  But are you very likely making two mistakes:

#### Display precision is not stored precision

Witness this:

```
R> options("digits.secs"=0); Sys.time()
[1] "2017-02-12 19:47:49 CST"
R> options("digits.secs"=6); Sys.time()
[1] "2017-02-12 19:47:53.378328 CST"
R>
```

Time is *always* at about microsecond precision with R but your *default* display may be suppressing subseconds.  They are always there:

```
R> now <- Sys.time()
R> now - trunc(now)
Time difference of 0.722091 secs
R>
```

#### Wrong import from Postgresql

I was the original mentor for the RPostgreSQL project during its Google Summer of Code.  Postgresql has *native* datetimes, and so does R. Never ever import times as characters.  The parsing issue disappear if you properly typecast your query.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Can't believe I got a comment from the original mentor for the RPostgreSQL!

Comment: oh by the way.. I literally lose time data! Once imported into dataframe, there's only date left. If I force time format, comes as 2017-02-12 00:00:00.. One table with 800 rows works fine, but not the one with 2.5mil rows. Not sure if it's the size that matters.. Only started using sql on R today and so much to learn!